# Understanding the notation and concept behind March Tests

Tags: algorithms, memory-access, software-testing

**Some background on my question:**

I have done some research into March Tests that are essentially access patterns for DRAM.

One example of these march tests in the MATS+ algorithm shown below with (I think) O(n) complexity:

MATS+: {⇕ (w0); ⇑(r0, w1); ⇓(r1)}

**Steps for algorithm:**

1) Write a 0 in either up or down addressing order.

2) Read a 0 and Write a 1 in up addressing order.

3) Read a 1 in down addressing order.

**My Question:**

My question is concerned with step 1) which is represented as ⇕ (w0) in my notation. If this step can be either up or down addressing order, what determines the direction of the addressing order? Does it simply mean two variants can exist for this algorithm that start with up addressing and down addressing order? Thanks in advance for any light shed on this.

I am also not clear on what is actual meant by up addressing and down addressing order. Is it the traversal direction of the DRAM cell or the memory?

Comment: This seems to be more about engineering than about computer science.

Comment: When you posted this earlier on CSTheory.SE, I gave you some feedback.  I don't see that tit has been addressed.  I'm not going to repeat, but I'll just ask this: where did you encounter this notation?  Can you credit the source where you encountered it?  If you don't understand what it means, I'm guessing you must have gotten it from somewhere else.